# Using linux sort on multiple files

Tags: linux, sorting

Is there a way I can run the following command with Linux for many files at once?

```
$ sort -nr -k 2 file1 > file2
```

Comment: `cat *|sort > file2`

Comment: `sort -nr -k 2 file1 file2 ... fileN > result`

Comment: Just call sort on all the files you want. sort .... file1 file2 > fileout

Comment: If you want the sorts to run in parallel, start each sort in the background.  There's an issue with the file naming.  But, for example: `for file in file.*; do sort -nr -k2 -o "$file.sort" "$file" & done` should run them in background, as long as you don't have too many files.  If you do, you need to look at GNU `parallel` or something similar.

Comment: Most of these replies aren't doing what the original question asked. Passing all the file names to `sort` will mix the output together, which isn't what they wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have many input files, and you want to create a sorted version of each of them.  I would do this using something like

```
for f in file*
do
    sort $f > $f.sort
done
```

Now, this has the small problem that if you run it again, if will not only sort all the files again, it will also create file1.sort.sort to go with file1.sort.  There are various ways to fix that.  We can fix the second problem by creating sorted files thate don't have names beginning with "file":

```
for f in file*
do
    sort $f > sorted.$f
done
```

But that's kind of weird, and I wouldn't want files named like that.  Alternatively, we could use a slightly more clever script that checks whether the file needs sorting, and avoids both problems:

```
for f in file*
do
    if expr $f : '.*\.sort' > /dev/null
    then
        : no need to sort
    elif test -e $f.sort
    then
        : already sorted
    else
        sort -nr -k 2 $f > $f.sort
    fi
done
```